# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-cli

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5100/MYService.asmx/Myweb-Method. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access.

I have problem in cordova visual studio.

What should i do please give me some suggestion

Comment: Use IP address, of your host computer

Comment: How  to do this? - @medet

Comment: localhost is alias for 192.168.0.1 or 0.0.0.0, so try to request this IP instead of localhost, and don't forget to append port

Comment: I already upload my project on IIS  (192.168.0.1:75) but it is not work there also it gives same error.

Comment: Try to enable CORS on your asp.net server app

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://enable-cors.org/server.html). Choose the server you use and it'll provide a code snippet, that should do the job.

Comment: I am Using webservices SOAP. then how could i add CORS?

Comment: please write down your javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) application from google chrome. Enable the CORS in the application installed and execute your code. This will temporarily allow the CORS in your browser.